# Golang Dep unable to read metadata

Tags: go, dep

I use this command:

```
dep init -gopath -v
```

in my gopath,like this:

```
gopath/src/aaa.com/bbb/ccc.v2
```

in my code, import is:

```
import ("aaa.com/bbb/ccc.v2")
```

final got this:

```
init failed: unable to determine direct dependencies: unable to deduce 
repository and source type for "aaa.com/bbb/ccc.v2": unable to 
read metadata: unable to fetch raw metadata: failed HTTP request to URL 
"http://aaa.com/bbb/ccc.v2?go-get=1": Get http://aaa.com/bbb/ccc.v2?go-get=1: context canceled
```

actually,aaa.com don`t exists,it just a dir in my gopath

WHY dep still request the network to get metadata even if I specified the `-gopath` param?